# My PHPUnit tests run, why should I add it as a dependancy in composer?

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php

I see I can add the following to my composer.json file:

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.2.*"
    }
}
```

But I have PHPUnit installed, I can run it from the command line without the above. Why would I install it as a dependency? Does that mean I don't need to install it?

Also, the following let's me install it globally - `composer global require "phpunit/phpunit=4.2.*"` - where is this set? If I install it globally, can I unrequire it later if I choose to install on a project by project basis. I'm really just finding my way around the framework and don't want to set anything I can't reverse.

http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to use a `require-dev` section for your development dependencies, if they are already on your development machines. If PHPUnit is already globally installed, there is no need to install it in your project.

When your project has a lot of developers, you can't pretend that all of them have PHPUnit installed globally. Also, the PHPUnit version used in your project might matter. By using the require-dev section you explicitly say, that this specific version is a development dependency. When working with Continuous Integration servers, some of them have PHPUnit installed globally, some of them, like Jenkins would need additional steps (like a global installation) then it becomes handy to install the dependency on a per-project level.

The command `composer global require "phpunit/phpunit=4.2.*"` will install PHPUnit and all its dependencies into the `~/.composer/vendor/` directory and the CLI tools into the bin folder `~/.composer/vendor/bin/`. As you can see this is a per user installation (`~`).
You can remove it by editing the `~/.composer/composer.json` file, removing the PHPUnit dependency and then running `composer global update`.